# Show calender on TextBox.GotFocus() event in MVVM

Tags: wpf, mvvm

I have an application which is having TextBox. Upon getting the focus, I need to show the Calendar as Popup.

My question is how to show subscribe the GotFocus event and show the calendar through view model?

Comment: The main question here is: why do you want to implement a pure UI feature (showing a popup) in your `ViewModel` ? Catching `GotFocus` event to set the `Popup`'s visibility to `true` should totally do the trick in an MVVM environment, since you are dealing with a pure UI change here

Comment: I agree with Damascus here. I would say the preferred way would be to use a trigger in your template to open the popup. Binding to IsFocused or IsKeyboardFocusWithin (I think) seems the way to go.

Comment: @Damascus I agreed with your point. My problem is, after showing the calender, any changes(date selection) in the calender I need to reflect in ViewModel and show the selected date as Text in Textbox. Any ideas would be appriciated...

Comment: Well, when you create a WPF `Popup`, you can put whatever you want inside (in your case, a Calendar, I guess). Just bind this calendar to your `ViewModel`, and any changes made on UI will be made in ViewModel as well. The `Popup` control is just a container which goes over other controls and can be visible or not :)

Comment: Thanks Damascus, your solution will work. My requirements is like this.I am using Textbox to show the date. Date can be either typed in Textbox or selected from Calendar. Finally if the date is valid then I am using that date for processing. In my case I need to reflect only date in the viewmodel. Any idea

Answer (score 4):

It is fairly acceptable to write code-behind for view-specific tasks like this one, however if you insist to have clean code-behind files , do the following

you will need MvvmLight.Extras.WPF4.dll and System.Windows.Interactivity.dll, the second DLL comes mainly with blend , google the first and at any case you can find them both on the MVVMLight package.

reference them as follows:

```
xmlns:cmd="clr-namespace:GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Command;assembly=GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Extras.WPF4"

xmlns:i="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Interactivity;assembly=System.Windows.Interactivity"
```

see your textBox

```
<TextBox>
<i:Interaction.Triggers>
 <i:EventTrigger EventName="GotFocus">
    <cmd:EventToCommand Command="{Binding showCalendar, Mode=OneWay}" MustToggleIsEnabledValue="True"/>
    </i:EventTrigger>
    </i:Interaction.Triggers>
</TextBox>
```

on your view model you should have a property that is bound to your Calendar Visibility property , change it to Visible inside the method invoked by the command.

Answer (score 2):

You really don't need to go to the ViewModel for this - it can be done very simply in XAML. Use a [BooleanToVisibilityConverter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.booleantovisibilityconverter.aspx) on a binding that is attached to the TextBox's IsFocused property.

```
            <TextBox x:Name="_textBox" Text="{Binding Text}" />
            <myNameSpace:Calendar Visibility="{Binding ElementName=_textBox, Path=IsFocused, Converter={x:Static _boolToVisibilityConverter}, Mode=OneWay}" />
```